# Docker-compose stop removes the data from tables in the database

Tags: python, postgresql, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Everytime I do "docker-compose restart", my initial entered data in the database is automatically removed. I see the data being added to the table but as soon as I do restart or stop the docker and start it again, it doesn't exist anymore. The empty table does exist, It just the data that is deleted. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
    app:
        build: .
        command: python app/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
        volumes:
            - ./:/app/
        ports:
            - 8000:8000
        env_file:
            - ./.env.dev
        depends_on:
            - db

    db:
        image: postgres
        volumes:
            - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
        environment:
            - POSTGRES_USER=cmpt_user
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
            - POSTGRES_DB=cmpt_project 
volumes:
    postgres_data:
```

Dockerfile

```
# pull official base image
FROM python:3.8.0-alpine
RUN apk update && apk add postgresql-dev gcc python3-dev musl-dev

# set work directory
WORKDIR /app

# set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# install dependencies
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
COPY ./requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# copy entrypoint.sh
COPY ./entrypoint.sh /app/entrypoint.sh

# copy project
COPY . /app/

# run entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/app/entrypoint.sh"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The docker-compose.yml looks good to me:

- You set up a persistent volume which is stored by default at `/var/lib/docker/volumes/<project>_postgres_data`
- by default `<project>` is the name of the folder the `docker-compose.yml` resides
- The volume **will survive** (I verified) a `docker-compose down` or `docker-compose restart`. See
  https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/restart/

### Not commiting database transaction

Maybe the python program opens a database transaction, insert data to the table(s), but does not commit the transaction therafter. See more about transaction management, auto-commit mode, rollback etc.

Would you mind to provide more information how you verified that your data really was in the tables?

### Named volume interferences (MacOS)

Maybe the named volume interferes with the anonymous volume created by the postgres image you are using. 
Please modify your `docker-compose.yaml` **named volume and environment**:

```
version: '3'

services:
    app:
        build: .
        command: python app/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
        volumes:
            - ./:/app/
        ports:
            - 8000:8000
        env_file:
            - ./.env.dev
        depends_on:
            - db
    db:
        image: postgres
        volumes:
            - postgres_data:/var/postgres_data  #<----- modify
        environment:
            - PGDATA: /var/postgres_data        #<----- add
            - POSTGRES_USER=cmpt_user
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
            - POSTGRES_DB=cmpt_project 
volumes:
    postgres_data:
```

Source: https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/5012

Comment: Tried removing "/" same output.

Comment: Verification process = 1. docker-compose up -d  2.docker-compose exec db psql --username=cmpt_user --dbname=cmpt_project  3. INSERT INTO TABLE() VALUES() and it confirmed that the values is inserted 4. docker-compose stop 5. docker-compose start 6. open database, the value doesn't exist

Comment: @MGM See **Named volume interferences** in answer

Comment: "Not commiting database transaction" - this was it. We have to commit the changes to the image so "docker commit <container_id> <message>" worked. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Sry I cannot really believe. This means postgres is storing data in image. But as you configured a *persitstant named volume* there is no need to commit image as data should be in the volume.
Thus, I suspect that on MacOS you need to do the workaround explained in **Named volume interferences**. Then you do not need to commit/persist the image changes and don't risk data loss as data is stored in image.

Comment: No no. Sorry. Everyone was right. The problem was in an external script which was flushing out all the data from the database. I am so sorry for confusing so much. My team just caught that error.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have misunderstood how volumes work.  At the bottom you have:

```
volumes:
    postgres_data:
```

When you do `docker-compose up`, it will do an implicit `docker volume create` and create the `postgres_data` volume.  If you do a `docker volume ls`, you might see something like:

```
$ docker volume ls | grep postgres_data
local               r_postgres_data
```

Then, if you look in `docker volume inspect r_postgres_data`, you'll see:

```
$ docker volume inspect r_postgres_data
[
    {
        "CreatedAt": "2020-02-07T19:43:11Z",
        "Driver": "local",
        "Labels": {
            "com.docker.compose.project": "r",
            "com.docker.compose.version": "1.24.1",
            "com.docker.compose.volume": "postgres_data"
        },
        "Mountpoint": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/r_postgres_data/_data",
        "Name": "r_postgres_data",
        "Options": null,
        "Scope": "local"
    }
]
```

I won't get into all the details here (you may want to consult the [Docker Community](https://forums.docker.com/t/host-path-of-volume/12277) on this).  Basically, a `docker-compose restart` wipes that volume and starts over.

All this to say that based on what you wrote in your original post, you're probably just looking to use a local folder, not a docker-created volume.  In this case, you need to add `./` to your path:

```
...
    db:
        image: postgres
        volumes:
            - ./postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
        environment:
            - POSTGRES_USER=cmpt_user
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
            - POSTGRES_DB=cmpt_project 
...
```

Comment: I understand what u r saying but ./postgres_data does not solve the problem. Also according to what I read everywhere named volumes are not wiped with restart. My problem is quite similar to this post here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51171239/docker-volume-doesnt-keep-data-after-turned-docker-compose-down/60120589?noredirect=1#comment106333019_60120589

Comment: Strange - what happens if you manually create a volume with `docker volume create` and then specify in your `docker-compose.yml` with `external: true`? (I just tried on my end and I don't see it getting wiped)

Comment: I tried it, it still doesn't work. No matter what, if I stop it and start it back again, all data is gone.

Comment: Two more questions: 1) How is your app container built, and 2) Are you using Windows?

Comment: 1) Added my Dockerfile in the question. 2) Mac

Comment: Verification process = 1. docker-compose up -d 2.docker-compose exec db psql --username=cmpt_user --dbname=cmpt_project 3. INSERT INTO TABLE() VALUES() and it confirmed that the values is inserted 4. docker-compose stop 5. docker-compose start 6. open database, the value doesn't exist