# How to make sure docker-compose will not remove my volume with postgres data

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I am running a simple django webapp with docker-compose. I define both a `web` service and a `db` service in a docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
  web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    env_file:
      - ./.env.dev
    depends_on:
      - db

volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

I start the service by running:

```
docker-compose up -d
```

I can load some data in there with a custom django command that I wrote for my app. Everything is running fine (with data) on localhost:8000.

However, when I run

```
docker-compose down
```

(so without `-v`) and then again

```
docker-compose up -d
```

the database is empty again. The volume was not persisted. From what I read in the [docker-compose docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/up/)  and also in several posts here at SO, persisting the volume and reusing it when you start a new container should be the default behavior (which, if I understand it correctly, you can disable by using the `--renew-anon-volumes` flag).

However in my case, the volume is not persisted. Or maybe it is, but my data is gone.

By doing `docker volume ls` I can see that my volume (I'll use the name `my_volume` here) still exists after the `docker-compose down` command. However, the `CreatedAt` value has been changed. This makes me think it's a different volume with the same name, and my data is already gone, but I don't know how to confirm that.

[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51174484/1805725) suggests to mount the volume on `/var/lib/postgresql` instead of `/var/lib/postgresql/data`. However, I've seen other resources (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41650891/1805725)) where the opposite is suggested. I've tried both, but neither option works.

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score -2):

It turns out that the Dockerfile of my app was using an entrypoint in which the following command was executed: `python manage.py flush` which clears all data in the database. As this gets executed every time the app container starts, it clears all data. It had nothing to do with docker-compose.